# Cannot set bool simple-prefs

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, preference

This is the preference I'm trying to set:

```
{
        "name": "datestamp",
        "title": "Date stamp?",
        "type": "bool",
        "value": true
    }
```

Heres the addon code,

`preference.js`

```
var preference = require("simple-prefs");

exports.set = function(preferenceTemp, value){
    console.log(value);
    preference.prefs[preferenceTemp] = value;
}
```

`main.js`

```
Preference = require("./Preference")

Preference.set('datestamp', true);
```

Error on console when trying to execute:

```
console.error: addon: 
  Message: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff 
  (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.setComplexValue]"  nsresult: "0x8000ffff 
  (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm
    -> jar:file:///tmp/tmpuc82Vi.mozrunner/extensions
    /addon@bobbyrne01.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit
    /loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/preferences/service.js :: set :: 
    line 92"  data: no]
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me - what versions of the SDK and Firefox are you using?

Comment: `Add-on SDK 1.14 (39467a307f58b63c1907c8d383e48475c98b0624)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was, I was passing in a string from elsewhere in my code that was not set as a boolean.
This did the trick:

```
Preference.set('datestamp', 'true' === "true");
```